# Query only working on PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I'm trying this query:

```
//connect;

$site = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['site']);

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Site = '$site'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    { 
    print $row['type'];
    }
```

doesn't print anything, running `SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Site = 'http://rollingstone.com/'` from PHPMyAdmin returns one row.

I'm sure it must be something really basic, since I haven't got much experience with MySQL.

I'm trying it here btw: http://www.chusmix.com/game/insert/get-items.php?site=http://rollingstone.com/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `$site` actually contains something; doing a quick `echo $site` before your `mysql_query()` should tell you this. If it's empty, try `print_r($_GET)` to see if it's in the `$_GET` array. It should be, but it might not for some other reason; check any code above this snippet for stuff that modifies `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` in any way.

To request data from a MySQL table, you need to connect to the server using [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), then select the database with [`mysql_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php). PHP *should* throw errors, but to be sure put these lines at the top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

All errors will now be shown.

In addition, you can also test for how many rows that were returned using `mysql_num_rows()`. For example:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($data) !== false)
{
    while(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No rows";
}
```

Will echo `No rows` if there weren't any results from the query. This is all error detection code; the cause of your error isn't obvious, so a little investigation is necessary, using the above methods (and any more you can think of).

Comment: I tried it, it returns true however the WHILE doesn't work. So there's the problem. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is to put `print_r($row)` in the `while()` loop. I have a feeling this will return an empty array, but if it doesn't, that's a start!

Comment: I checked for error, didn't realise I wasn't and I'm getting: `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #2' at line 1`

Answer (score 0):

Have you called `mysql_select_db('your_database_name');` on the connection first? Have you tried echoing out the SQL before it's executed to confirm that Site is what you expect it to be?

Comment: I echoed site and $data. http://www.chusmix.com/game/insert/get-items.php?site=http://rollingstone.com/
site is echoed alright data echoes Resource id #2

Comment: Is PHP able to see the "type" column?
Try my code with the code bellow the `/* get column metadata */` comment in [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php). Check if all the columns in `Items` shows up ok.

Comment: I checked for error, didn't realise I wasn't and I'm getting: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #2' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Site ='%s'",
   mysql_real_escape_string($site));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Just to be on the safe side (avoid [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

Comment: I checked for error, didn't realise I wasn't and I'm getting: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #2' at line 1